# Does there exist an explicit formula for calculating $\sin(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Here's my idea. We have sets $C=\{(x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $L = \{ (x,y) : x,y,k \in \mathbb{R} \land y = kx \}$. Their intersection can be written as $C \cap L = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \land y = kx \}$. By substituting $kx$ for $y$, we obtain a formula whose solutions for $x$ will be the $x$ coordinates of the points in the intersection.

\begin{align*}
x^2 + (kx)^2 &= 1 \\
x^2 &= \frac{1}{1 + k^2} \\
x &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + k^2}}.
\end{align*}

The motivation for this equation is that if we could somehow express $k$ in terms of radians, we would have a general equation for calculating $\sin(x)$ for any real value. (Here, we are assuming the definition of $\sin$ as the $x$ coordinate of the intersection between a unit circle and a ray, determined by some angle $\theta$.)

I haven't been able to find an equation for $k(\theta)$, but I suspect that it is $\tan(\theta)$ (as some nice values, such as $0$ and $\pi/4$ give the correct results for $k$: $0$ and $1$ respectively), which is problematic, since $\tan$ is usually defined by $\sin$, and if it weren't, we would have to define it independently first in order to obtain an equation for $\sin$. I also suspect that an explicit formula for $\sin(x)$ doesn't exist, as we would have learned it early on in school if it were so easy.

So, what's your thoughts on this? Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: $\sin(x)$ *is* an explicit formula for expression the sine of the angle $x$, and is probably as good as you are ever going to get.  The sine function is not algebraic, thus you are never going to find an algebraic function which gives $\sin(x)$ for arbitrary real $x$.  You can *approximate* $\sin(x)$ to arbitrary precision (e.g. using Taylor series expansions), and $\sin(m 2^{-n} \pi)$ can be computed exactly in terms of radicals using angle addition / half-angle formulæ (for example).  But these kinds are results are the best you are going to be able to do.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks, this answers my question. Consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Maclaurin/Taylor series for $\sin(x)$:

$$\sin(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

You can read more on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series or watch 3b1b’s YouTube video on Taylor series in his Essence of Calculus playlist.